# Trying to delete several thousand users from database

Tags: mysql, joomla

I checked one of my Joomla! websites this evening and to my horror found that I had thousands of spam registrations. I can't bring up all the users on one page on the **website because it crashes, it's obviously too much for the server.**

**Even if I display 100 users per page, I've got 500 pages, it will take me until next week to delete them.** So I thought maybe I can do from the database. The same thing happened, if I have 30 users showing, there are over 1000 pages. So I change the setting to show 1000 users, I wasn't able to delete the 1000 user because the page just crashed again.

So I'm thinking that maybe I can backup my own account from the user table. However, do I have to create another user table in order to reinstall my account? I hope you understand my dilemma

Comment: This site is for programming questions. How to maintain your site is offtopic.

Comment: No it's really somewhat of a programming question because it shoudl be done programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete every user except your own you could do :

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE email != 'your_email';
```

**Please note this will delete every other account**

Be sure to make a backup of your database first.

If you want to remove emails with a certain extension :

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%.co.uk';
DELETE FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%gmail.com';
```

Comment: More complex query to choose rows to delete (to decide if value is suspected as spam) can be **regular expression**, something like: inline `DELETE FROM users WHERE email REGEXP 'regular expression'`. See [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) .

Answer (score 2):

What I might do is go to phpmyadmin and export any data you want to keep even one at a time.

Then empty the table (i.e. delete all the rows).

Then import all of the data you exported back into the empty table.

Of it's just the one record you want to keep @Sparkup's answer will be quicker though.

Were you using a user profile plugin? If so you'll want to delete any records there also.

Then at minimum enable recaptcha, but also if you don't really want user registration, turn that off in the global configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Delete would be a good choice. Access Joomla database from terminal(linux) or cmd(windows) that would be fast .using captcha might be useful to stop spamming at certain extent.